# Limit points of a subset are limit points of the superset - confusion

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Need some help in understanding [this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387216/limit-points-of-a-subset).

The proof given by OP seems valid. Yet, top-rated answer provides a more complex proof, that I don't understand.

I don't understand what is the problem with OP's proof.

Then again, if someone could explain what is meant by "a neighborhood of $p$ **in $E$**".. Does it mean a neighborhood of a point $p$ *belonging* (the point) to $E$?

### OP's Proof that seems valid:

Let $E\subset K$

If every neighborhood of $p\in E$ contains a point $q\neq p$ such that $q\in E$, then this $q$ is also in $K$, then $p$ is a limit point of $K$.

PS: all the answers to this other [SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410517/baby-rudin-theorem-2-27c) seem to confirm that the above-written short proof is valid.

Comment: The phrase "a neighborhood of $p$ in $E$" means an $E$-neighborhood of $p$ (i.e. $p \in E$ and the neighborhood  is a neighborhood in the **space** $E).$ On the other hand, "a neighborhood of $p$ in $K$ means a $K$-neighborhood of $p$ (i.e. $p \in K$ and the neighborhood is a neighborhood in the **space** $K).$ Now if $E \subseteq K,$ then $p \in E$ implies $p \in K.$ Also, by the subspace metric definition, every neighborhood in $E$ (in particular, every $E$-neighborhood of $p)$ is a neighborhood in $K$ (in particular, every $E$-neighborhood of $p$ is a $K$-neighborhood of $p).$ *(continued)*

Comment: Incidentally, I think there is an ambiguity in the statement of the problem. Are we looking at limit points ONLY in the space $X$ in which $E$ and $K$ are subsets of, and considering the notion of an $X$-limit point when looking at limit points of the **sets** $E$ and $K$ within the space $X$ (what it seems to be asking to me), or are we considering $E$ and $K$ as spaces themselves and looking at $E$-limit points and $K$-limit points (2nd answer; maybe 1st answer, but the 1st answer seems a bit unclear to me)?

Comment: Oh I didn't the notion of $E$-limit point and $E$-neighborhood. Now I understand a bit better

Comment: There is a notion called "absolute property" (also called "intrinsic property"; and when the property is not an absolute property, then it's called a "relative property") that might be useful to google. Compactness and connectedness are absolute properties (of sets/spaces), whereas being a closed set is a relative property (if $E \subseteq K \subseteq X$ and $E$ is a closed subset of the **space** $K,$ then $E$ might not be a closed subset of the **space** $X$ -- example: $(0,1) \subseteq (0,2) \subseteq {\mathbb R}).$ The 2nd answer is showing that being a limit point is an absolute property.

Answer (score 1):

To show $p$ is a limit point of $K$, we have to show that every neighbourhood of the point $p$ contains at least one point of $K$ other than $p$.

Now the given condition says that every neighbourhood of the point $p$ contains a point $q$ of $E$ other than $p$ and $E\subseteq K$. So, $q$ is a point of $K$  other than $p$. Hence $p$ is a limit point of $K$.